# Insert query works on phpMyAdmin but not with Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse

I have a problem with this query :

```
insert into PLAYER(PSEUDO, EMAIL, PASSWORD) values("Test","test@test.fr",md5('pass'));
```

It works on phpMyAdmin, but in Eclipse it goes in the catch...

Can you tell me why ?

EDIT:

```
            // Si un textfield n'est pas renseignŽ (length=0), on affiche un
            // MessageDialgo...Sinon, on proc�de ˆ l'inscription (insert...)
            if (tfRegisterPseudo.getText().length() == 0
                    || tfRegisterEmail.getText().length() == 0
                    || tfRegisterPassword.getPassword().length == 0)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "You forgot something...");
            else {
                query = "insert into PLAYER(PSEUDO, EMAIL, PASSWORD) "
                        + "values(\"" + tfRegisterPseudo.getText()
                        + "\",\"" + tfRegisterEmail.getText() 
                        + "\",md5('" + String.valueOf(tfRegisterPassword.getPassword()) + "'));";
                transmission.executeUpdate(query);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successfully registered !");
            }

            setContentPane(buildLogin());
            this.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception m) {
            // TODO Recuperer l'erreur de la BD et l'afficher
            System.out.println("An error occured.");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"An error occured.");
            System.out.println(query);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your java code?

Comment: and the stack trace since it goes into the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you use md5, which is a php-function. In java using the md5 hash algorithm will have to be called in a different manner.